# Do the new system fonts make it easier for you to read Spanish letters and accents?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Do the new [system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1) make it easier for you to read Spanish letters and accents (á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡) ?

I use Firefox 88 on Windows 10 and they are definitely good although I can't say if they are actually *better* than they were.

Regular font  (á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡) non accented i

Bold font **(á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡) non accented i**

Italic font  *(á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡) non accented i*

[Spanish letters](https://www.spanishdict.com/answers/282262/how-to-type-spanish-letters-and-accents-from-paralee)

Comment: Another way to do Spanish accent marks is to put the International Keyboard on your PC. Them, you can type them all using one extra key.